# Increasing number of presets for layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, numbering

Working with a map and make the schema the corresponding set of layers, save as a preset(very comfortable) but after 12 presets become unavailable menu to add preset.

Can you can then add the number of presets in QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @DanielDem! Which QGIS version and platform are you using? I tested on 2.18.14 for Win7 64-bit and could make 20+ presets. Are you sure existing presets do not match your current set of checked/unchecked layers? I don't think you can have multiple presets with the same set of layers checked (i.e. if _layerA_ and _layerB_ were checked and you made a preset, you cannot make another preset).